# Indexed list of files in a folder that match a criteria

Tags: python, directory, os.walk

I'm trying to list all files in a folder that match `MySample %i %j.wav` (where `%i`, `%j` should be integers), but instead of having the result like this (I tried `glob.glob('MySample *.wav')`):

```
["MySample 117 12.wav", "MySample 011 18.wav", "MySample 13 45.wav"]
```

I would like to have **something that would be indexed by the patterns variable %i, %j** :

```
{(117, 12): "MySample 117 12.wav", 
 (11, 18): "MySample 011 18.wav", 
 (13, 45) : "MySample 13 45.wav"}
```

Comment: so you have other files starting with `MySample` and ending in `.wav`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is rather straightforward using regexps:

```
import os, re


samples = {}
for f in os.listdir("."):
    m = re.match(r"MySample (\d+) (\d+).wav", f)
    if m:
        samples[tuple(int(x) for x in m.groups())] = f
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regexp to match

```
import re

def getKey(x):
  m=re.match ('MySample (\d+) (\d+).wav',x)                                                                                                                                                                     
  if m:
    return (m.group(1),m.group(2))                                                                                                                                                                              
  else:
    return None

sample=["MySample 117 12.wav", "MySample 011 18.wav", "MySample 13 45.wav"]
```

Then a list comprehension to create the dictionary

```
r=dict(((getKey(x),x) for x in sample))
```